# I want to make a shopping website, which technology can i use for front-end and back-end for best performance

Tags: web-development

I want to make a shopping website, which technology can i use for front-end and back-end for best performance.

Comment: Must you code it all from scratch? That sounds like reinventing the wheel and could take months or years to do. Would you be willing to use an existing solution, such as Drupal? Have a look at [CMS Matrix](http://cmsmatrix.org/) and use it’s wizard to find the best CMS for you.

Comment: You can use prestashop & opencart, oscarcommerce(django). All are open source.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your performance is not the only thing to consider. What about development speed. There are many frameworks and CMS that help you built a nice webshop.

Woocommerce for Wordpress for example or Aimeos for Laravel. They would kickstart building your webshop and both have probably a more than good enough performance. There are many more tools to choose from and the raw performance does vary but also depends on the code you will write to customize the site. Do yourself a favor and use the most useful tool for your problem.